# Push an item into a JSON Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I have a JavaScript function that makes an ajax call to an API, and gets a JSON array.

Here is a sample of an array that I get:

```
[
  {
    "ErrorType": "Errors",
    "Explanations": [
      {
        "Explanation": "Price Missing",
        "Locations": [
          25,
          45
        ]
      },
      {
        "Explanation": "Unit of measurement not valid",
        "Locations": [
          25,
          301,
          302
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ErrorType": "Warnings",
    "Explanations": [
      {
        Blablabla,
        Ithinkthere's already much here
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I put it into a JavaScript array:

```
$scope.CorrectionDatas = ResponseFromApi;
```

So, for each ErrorType, I have some "explanations". I would like to add another property, in order to have something like this :

```
[
  {
    "ErrorType": "Errors",
    "Explanations": [
      {
        "Explanation": "Price Missing",
        "Locations": [
          25,
          45
        ]
      },
      {
        "Explanation": "Unit of measurement not valid",
        "Locations": [
          25,
          301,
          302
        ]
      }
    ],
    "show": true
  },
  {
    "ErrorType": "Warnings",
    "Explanations": [
      {
        Blablabla,
        Ithinkthere's already much here 
      }
     ],
    "show":true
  }
]
```

I though that I could do it only by doing it like that:

```
$scope.CorrectionDatas.forEach(function (error) {
    error.push({ show: true });
});
```

But my debugger gives me an error:

```
Error: error.push is not a function 
$scope.getErrors/</<@http://localhost:1771/dependencies/local/js/Correction/CorrectionCtrl.js:26
```

Comment: The problem is that while the JSON response constitutes an array, each element of that array is an object, not an array. I.e `{"ErrorType":"Warnings", "Explanations":[{ Blablabla, I think there's already much here }]}` is an object...

Comment: Can you please show the output of 'typeof error'? I believe this to be an object, not an array.

Comment: as it is said, I received an object, thx for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$scope.CorrectionDatas.forEach(function (error){
     error["show"] = true;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Each error is an object so it don't have push, the code should be:

```
        $scope.CorrectionDatas.forEach(function(error) {
            error.show = true;
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the problem you're encountering is that `error` is not an array, it is an object. This can be confirmed by logging the output of `typeof error`. If this is the case, you must explicitly define the `show` property of the object, as so:

```
$scope.CorrectionDatas.forEach(function (error){
    error['show'] = true; // alternatively, error.show = true;   
});
```